# lodash uniqWith with an array of objects

Tags: lodash

i have an array of objects like:

`[{id: '123', name: 'John', someKey:'1234'}, {id: '123', name: 'John', someKey:'12345'}]`

this is only a basic example, the data is much more complicated so `_.isEqual` doesn't work.

what do I do with the comparator? I wanna compare the `id` if they are equal.

`_.uniqWith(myArray, function(something) {return something})`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Compare the ids in the `_.uniqWith()` comparator function or use `_.uniqBy()`:

```js
var myArray = [{
  id: '123',
  name: 'John',
  someKey: '1234'
}, {
  id: '123',
  name: 'John',
  someKey: '12345'
}]

var result = _.uniqWith(myArray, function(arrVal, othVal) {
  return arrVal.id === othVal.id;
});

console.log(result);

/** using uniqBy **/

var result = _.uniqBy(myArray, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is it possible to use uniqWith but take the last value?

Comment: Reverse the array, use uniqBy/With, and reverse the results.

Comment: @Amityo what does it mean ?

Comment: Choosing the last unique value and not the first one. @Idan

Comment: So i think the best way is reversing the array as @OriDrori said

Comment: I found that the alternative _.isEqual function did NOT work, if used as the comparator.